# rxjava - Publish Processor race condition

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

Hi I'm new to RxJava and the whole reactive programming idea, And I would like some help understanding a few concepts.

Here is the thing, I have this class that dispatches messages, this class has an Inner PublishProcessor, which is what I thought was the best solution to being able to publish messages dynamically, since it seems that Observable/Flowable are born from alredy existant or received data, say, I could not handle the push of a button N times.

So this class has this dispatch(SomeClass c) that calls the OnNext method of my publisher, effectively sending data to every subscriber at the time.
But say a Network request finishes at the exact same time a button is pushed, both messages collide and none get effectively sent, and the docs say this is expected behavior.

How would you handle this situation? this is basically it.

```
private ObservableList<ObservableResponse> list;

public static class ObservableList<T> {

    protected final PublishProcessor<T> onAdd;

    public ObservableList() {
        this.onAdd = PublishProcessor.create();
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        onAdd.onNext(value);
    }

    public io.reactivex.Observable<T> getObservable() {
        return onAdd.toObservable();
    }

    public PublishProcessor<T> getProcessor(){
        return onAdd;
    }

}

private MessageStream(){
    this.list = new ObservableList<>();
}

public static class helper{
    public static MessageStream instance = new MessageStream();
}

public void dispatchMessage(ObservableResponse x ){
    this.list.add(x);
}
```

Observable response is a POJO in itself.

Any help would be appreciated, I know the docs are strong, yet there is a lot more about rx1 than rx2, so I got confused real hard...

Comment: I'm not sure why you have created the `ObservableList` wrapper around the `PublishProcessor`; it's needless boilerplat. To create a thread-safe processor, you use `PublishSubject.create().toSerialized()`. This processor will then make sure that emissions from different threads occur in a distinct order.

Comment: Boilerplate indeed,  it had a good reason but it proved to be unnecessary, thanks for the answer! I'll try that